# Oracle REGEXP to replace only the first character

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

In the example below:

```
WITH X(DATA, ORD)
AS
(         
Select '@asdf@'   , 01 FROM DUAL UNION
Select '\qw@er\'  , 02 FROM DUAL UNION
Select '-zxcv-@' , 03  FROM DUAL UNION
Select '_poiu@' ,  04 FROM DUAL 
)

SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE(DATA, '[@\-_]', '', 1)
FROM X
ORDER BY ORD;  
;
```

I get this response:

```
asdf 
qwer
-zxcv- 
poiu
```

But I would like to replace the "@", or the "\" or the "-" or the "_" only if it is the first character on the string, not in the middle.
Plus it is not working for the "-" character.

Answer (score 2):

The following regex should work: `^[@\\_-]`. Note that the dash `-` must be the last character in the character class.

```
WITH X AS (
  SELECT '@asdf@' AS data, 01 AS ord FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT '\qw@er\', 02 FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT '-zxcv-@', 03  FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT '_poiu@',  04 FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(DATA, '^[@\\_-]')
 FROM X
ORDER BY ORD
```

Comment: It doesn't hurt, but you don't even need the double backslash; it's a literal anyway within the square-bracketed [matching character list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDIEGEI), with no special meaning. (And the dash can come first or last, just not in the middle where it would denote a range - [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40568)).

Comment: I almost always over-\-compensate :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead, use this

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(DATA, '^[@|\\|-|_]', '', 1)
```

Notice the `^` character which specify the begining of the string.

The query

```
WITH X(DATA, ORD)
AS
(         
Select '@asdf@'   , 01 FROM DUAL UNION
Select '\qw@er\'  , 02 FROM DUAL UNION
Select '-zxcv-@' , 03  FROM DUAL UNION
Select '_poiu@' ,  04 FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE(DATA, '^[@|\\|-|_]', '', 1)
FROM X
ORDER BY ORD;
```

Gave me the result

> asdf@, qw@er, zxcv@, poiu@,

Comment: Thank you, but no. Your regex is removing the "\" everywhere and the "-" everywhere, I just want it to be removed the first one.

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.4

Comment: You don't need those pipe `|` characters in the character class - the following should suffice: `^[@\\_-]`. Note I'm putting the dash at the end because otherwise it has a particular meaning in a character class enclosed in `[]`.